Change backgroun color of directory in Konsole's Kubuntu Terminal
See the ScreenShot
As you can see, there are two things with that green color:
- The text "SUCCESS"
- And the background of directories/files when using the LS command to navigate.

If I change, editing the profile theme, the color of green, I can make that ugly background disappear, but the color code is the same for the text "SUCCESS" (and others words in common terminal usage).
The problem is that I can't change the background color of the directories independently of the words that use the same color code.
-
I just want to make disapear the ugyl Background color of directories, to make it easy to see an read.

Configure $LS_COLORS to stop coloring directories this way.
